# Setting up Foreign key like references in EF code first

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have a set of four POCO objects that need to reference themselves in this way:

A Freelancer can have multiple Clients

Clients can have multiple Projects

Projects can have multiple Stories.

One this I want to make sure is possible is that a freelancer starts off with no clients, and client starts off with no projects, and a project starts off with no stories, so I guess they need to be nullable?

The opposite is true the other direction, a story NEEDS a project, project needs a client, and a client needs a freelancer.

I just want to see if there is anything that I need to do when I am creating the model (onModelCreating override) to make sure this is the relationship that happens.

Here are my objects:

```
public class Freelancer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
    public Address FreelancerAddress { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}


public class Client
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address ClientAddress { get; set; }
    public string Logo { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}


public class Project
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Story> Stories { get; set; }
}


 public class Story
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public decimal Duration { get; set; }
    public bool Billable { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

I understand EF does some things automatically, I am just asking if there is more I need to do to make sure I have the relationship I want. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention your model will create *optional* relationships ("client *can* have a freelancer but doesn't need to") but since you want required relationships ("client *needs* a freelancer") you must define it with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Freelancer>()
    .HasMany(f => f.Clients)
    .WithRequired()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("FreelancerID"));  // FK column name in Clients table
```

You can work without the last line (`Map`). EF will then create a default foreign key name, something with underscore, maybe `Freelancer_ID`.

And the same mapping for the other relationships.

Alternatively you can introduce inverse navigation properties with foreign key properties:

```
public class Client
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    //...
    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    public int FreelancerID { get; set; }
    public Freelancer Freelancer { get; set; }
}
```

With such a model EF will recognize the relationships as required automatically because the foreign key property `FreelancerID` is not nullable and you don't need additional mapping with Fluent API.

Comment: Liking the last part, just one clarification. If I have a Client have one Freelancer and then have a property called FreelancerId, EF will recognize that as the FK without any explicit settings?

Comment: @davidisawesome: Yes, because of the convention: *If there is a navigation reference with name XYZ (`Freelancer`) to target class ABC (`Freelancer` too in this case) with key property DEF (`ID`) and a scalar property with the same type as the key property in the target class (`int`) and a name composed of the navigation property's name and the key property of the target class (`Freelancer`+`ID` = `FreelancerID`) then this scalar property is considered as representing the foreign key.* (whew!) If you would change the name to for example `FreelanceCode` you need annotations or Fluent API.